# How do I commit changes to a text file on button press?

Tags: python

I've written a small [app that creates a GUI](http://www.reddit.com/r/ubuntuappshowdown/comments/vbo7y/my_app_idea_ushare_gui/) for setting up uShare. Currently it depends heavily on the 'w' (write) and 'a' (append) functions to generate/edit ushare.conf file. But I've been trying to find a way for the app to store all the changes until a save button is pressed, and only then committing them to the actual file. I think that would be the best way of getting around having the user press enter every time they change any field (and indeed allow for GtkCheckButton).

The code giving me errors, (and any code where I use StringIO has the same result:

```
 def on_userinput_activate(self, widget):
    usrinpt = widget.get_text()
    global output
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    output.write(usrinpt)


def on_savetofile_clicked(self, widget):
    global output
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    global inserttofile
    inserttofile = output.getvalue()
    logfile = open('/home/boywithaxe/Desktop/test.txt', 'w')
    logfile.write(inserttofile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build up a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) "pseudo-file" and write that to disk when finished.

Comment: +1 because this is a drop-in solution for what you're already doing. StringIO objects behave identically to file objects (so just replace your file object with a  StringIO object, and hey, presto!)

Comment: I'm almost there, I can see that StringIO is gathering all the data I want but now I need to figure out a way to write it to the file. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @boywithaxe: the `getvalue` method will return the accumulated contents of a `StringIO`, as a string.

Comment: I've used get value, and I hat to use global variables, but it fails between getting the string from `getvalue()` to writing it in a specified file. `def on_userinput_activate(self, widget):
        usrinpt = widget.get_text()
        global output
        output = StringIO.StringIO()
        output.write(usrinpt)
        

    def on_savetofile_clicked(self, widget):
        global output
        output = StringIO.StringIO()
        global inserttofile
        inserttofile = output.getvalue()
        logfile = open('/home/boywithaxe/Desktop/test.txt', 'w')
        logfile.write(inserttofile)`

Comment: @boywithaxe: please post that as a new question and include the full backtrace. These comment boxes are no good for posting code.

Comment: @larsmans: I added it to the starting post. Also it is worth nothing, I get no errors from the code, it simply just doesn't dump the string into the file, but it creates the file without a problem.

Comment: @boywithaxe: in `on_savetofile_clicked`, you're building a new, empty, `StringIO` object, overwriting the one you built in the other function.

Comment: @larsman: Doesn't using `global output` mean that it should refer to the `output` from the previous def block? If I omit that line from `on_savetofile_clicked` I get `NameError: global name 'output' is not defined`.

Comment: @boywithaxe: `global` means that you're handling the same name (variable), so that `output = StringIO()` rebinds that name and the interpreter forgets the value previously bound to that name.

Comment: That did it, thank you for all your help. I think I should have actually learned python before I started coding in it and diving in with no experience in python